# Solr: Boosting search results based on tag popularity

Tags: java, search, solr, hashtag

I have indexed airlines into my solr, one document per one airline, each user can search for airlines and also leave a tag about them. Lets say I used Airline X and I loved the service so I would leave a tag saying "great service". So over time people that leave same tag these tags get aggregated and we store the count how many times same tag has been left.

Now the question is, how would I boost the results if I start typing "great service" so that the airline with most tags of "great service" comes to the top of search results?

Answer (score -1):

you can use elevate.xml file in config folder and just mention which document to appear first in the resultset for specific searchTerm string.